# How many languages can Kingpin speak?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, daredevil

In the Daredevil TV series, we see **Wilson Fisk** speaking with Madame Gao in Mandarin (which is said to be intelligible, but pretty bad).

[image]

- **Which other languages he knows as well?**
- **When did he learn them?**

There's been only one season of Daredevil TV series, and I haven't seen Kingpin in any other movies or TV shows, but I'm Interested in both comics and cinematic universe.

Inspiration:

[Quora - "Marvel's Daredevil (TV series): How good is Wilson Fisk's Mandarin?"](https://www.quora.com/Marvels-Daredevil-TV-series/How-good-is-Wilson-Fisks-Mandarin)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**He speaks at least English, Mandarin, and Japanese.**

Madame Gao at one point asks him if he suspects that Nobu knows he speaks Japanese.

> After Wilson murdered his father, his mother sent him to live on a farm with relatives. Fisk later moved to Asia where he would spend most of his time abroad, something reflected in his behavior and clothing. [MCU Wiki](http://marvelcinematicuniverse.wikia.com/wiki/Wilson_Fisk)

This is likely when he learned Mandarin and Japanese.